# Tensorflow Dataset API: dataset.batch(n).prefetch(m) prefetches m batches or samples?

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

If I use

```
dataset.batch(n).prefetch(m),
```

m batches or m samples will be prefetched?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`Dataset.prefetch(m)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) transformation prefetches `m` elements of its direct input. In this case, since its direct input is `dataset.batch(n)` and each element of that dataset is a batch (of `n` elements), it will prefetch `m` **batches**.

Comment: Thanks so much! By the way, I want to ask another question: Does dataset.map(map_func, num_parallel_calls=num_threads) affect the data order if num_threads > 1?

Comment: As long as `map_func` is a pure function (i.e. it doesn't refer to mutable state like variables or random number generators) then the output should be identical with and without `num_parallel_calls > 1`.

Comment: hey, @mrry, the argument's name "buffer_size" and api_doc "Creates a Dataset that prefetches elements from this dataset." mislead users, can be more clear.