# tf.dataset.prefetch() buffer_size meaning

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

```
dataset = dataset.batch(50)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=1)
```

Is it prefetch 1 batch or 1 element?

Per the API document in tensorflow, the buffer_size is the max num of elements prefetch. But it seems it is num of batch after batching the dataset.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444018/meaning-of-buffer-size-in-dataset-map-dataset-prefetch-and-dataset-shuffle

Comment: but this post answer didn't clarify whether an element means a batch(if we call .batch() before the prefetch call) or a sample.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707062/tensorflow-dataset-api-dataset-batchn-prefetchm-prefetches-m-batches-or-sam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow Dataset API: dataset.batch(n).prefetch(m) prefetches m batches or samples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707062/tensorflow-dataset-api-dataset-batchn-prefetchm-prefetches-m-batches-or-sam)

Comment: yes, it got answered.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using `dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=1)` after `dataset.batch()`, it means that **it will prefetch 1 batch**.