# Tensorflow 1.11 estimator + dataset training speed low and irregular

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

**Problem**

- training a custom tensorflow 1.11 `tf.estimator.Estimator` with a `tf.data.Dataset` runs much more slowly than when using `tf.keras` with the same model architecture and feeding the data directly
- However, it does run quickly at times (in terms of global_step/sec), but is slow around epoch start and end.
- during the "fast" batches, GPU util is around 30%. During the slow ones, around 1%

**Probable causes**

- my input pipeline isn't well-optimized enough so that GPU is idle, waiting on the CPU data processing. But I don't understand why that's only in the last few minibatches before episode end

**What have I tried**

Followed the steps in the [Input Pipeline Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance). That sped up the batches that are not near epoch boundaries. I'm not sure how to improve further.

**Minimal working example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

train_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1030255, 1021)).rename(columns={c:str(c) for c in range(1021)})
train_target = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(1030255, 15))).rename(columns={c:str(c) for c in range(15)})
val_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(491077, 1021)).rename(columns={c:str(c) for c in range(1021)})
val_target = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(491077, 15))).rename(columns={c:str(c) for c in range(15)})

def model_fn(features, labels, mode,params): 
    net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])
    net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=params['hidden_units'], activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(net, params['outputs'], activation=None)
    loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(labels, logits=logits)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss)
    elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

cols = [str(c) for c in np.sort(np.random.choice(1021, size=98, replace=False))]
target_cols = [str(c) for c in np.arange(11)]
VALIDATION_BATCH_SIZE = int(val_data.shape[0] / 4.0)
BATCH_SIZE = 2**10

def train_input_fn():
    features = {k: train_data[k].values for k in cols}
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, train_target[target_cols].values))
    dataset = dataset.repeat() \
        .shuffle(train_data.shape[0]) \
        .batch(BATCH_SIZE) \
        .prefetch(BATCH_SIZE)
    return dataset

def validation_input_fn():
    features = {k: val_data[k].values for k in cols}
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, val_target[target_cols].values))
    dataset = dataset.repeat() \
        .batch(VALIDATION_BATCH_SIZE) \
        .prefetch(VALIDATION_BATCH_SIZE)
    return dataset

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(f) for f in cols]
run_cfg = tf.estimator.RunConfig(tf_random_seed=1, save_checkpoints_steps=1000, save_checkpoints_secs=None)
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        config=run_cfg,
        params={
            'feature_columns': feature_columns,
            'hidden_units': 128,
            'outputs': len(target_cols)
        })
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
    classifier,
    train_spec=tf.estimator.TrainSpec(train_input_fn),
    eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(validation_input_fn, steps=4, start_delay_secs=30, throttle_secs=30))
```

**Sample output**

(The time the first step takes is misrepresented as being huge since tensorflow takes the difference with the last training step. However, that is not the case for the last training step before starting eval.)

```
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2018-10-31-08:17:35
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1000: global_step = 1000, loss = 0.694723
INFO:tensorflow:Saving 'checkpoint_path' summary for global step 1000: /tmp/tmpvQq9DV/model.ckpt-1000
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.930553
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.69407356, step = 1000 (107.463 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 171.673
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.69456786, step = 1100 (0.583 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 166.964
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.69411445, step = 1200 (0.599 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 172.226
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6940959, step = 1300 (0.579 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 170.882
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.69440323, step = 1400 (0.586 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 173.453
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.69332886, step = 1500 (0.577 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 167.078
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6950055, step = 1600 (0.598 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 159.763
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.69460225, step = 1700 (0.626 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 161.674
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6940766, step = 1800 (0.617 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 8.83793
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6936994, step = 1900 (11.315 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 2000 into /tmp/tmpvQq9DV/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-10-31-08:18:11
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/tmpvQq9DV/model.ckpt-2000
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/4]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [2/4]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [3/4]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [4/4]
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2018-10-31-08:19:36
```

**Without eval step**

I thought the eval step (which in itself is freakishly slow) could be the issue. But when I only train, it runs even more slowly:

```
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=5000)

[...]
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1000 into /tmp/tmpIJctNp/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 6.95414
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6948092, step = 1000 (14.381 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 12.0491
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6942879, step = 1100 (8.298 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 8.98388
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6939402, step = 1200 (11.131 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 8.86219
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6946343, step = 1300 (11.284 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 8.74248
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.694865, step = 1400 (11.439 sec)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at how many bathes you can prefetch with performance improvement?
The performance guide you have shared recommends setting the buffer size based on how much you are processing. Have you tried with lower values of that buffer size, like prefetch(1)?

Comment: Ah, thanks, I now understand that buf size in prefetch refers to nr of elements of previous operation, so in this case nr of batches (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707062/tensorflow-dataset-api-dataset-batchn-prefetchm-prefetches-m-batches-or-sam). I tried setting it to 1, but that's much slower.

Comment: By the way, I now discovered tensorpack (https://github.com/tensorpack/tensorpack), which on the same dataset and model achieves about 3.5s per epoch (i.e. per 1000 steps as per original example), **including** validation. So it's about 30x faster than my implementation above. GPU util is around 40%. I'll leave this question open though out of interest.

Comment: interesting! It would be great to get some insight in to where in the pipeline tensorpack is solving the throughput bottleneck. From the surface level looks of it, maybe something to do with better handling of the various buffers and internal queues?

Comment: @kvish if I'd have to guess, these are some factors: 1) tensorpack uses raw python instead of a graph for data processing; 2) it's easy to parallelize batching & prefetching; 3) I suspect one reason why my tf implementation above is slow is that it has to re-create and initialize the graph for each eval, including (I guess) some static data assignment. tensorpack doesn't do this (I'm sure there are complicated ways of avoiding this in tensorflow too)